# Adding IDENTITY insert to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on rolling my own cube and I have a table that looks something like

```
drug_class      drug_name
h3b             drug x
h4b             drug y
h2f             drug z
```

these columns are not the primary key and can be repeated N times for every record in the table.  I want to make a dimension out of them for my cube and was wondering if it's possible to do an identity insert into a view like

```
create view [My Dimension] as
select distinct drugID int identity,drug_class,drug_name
from myTable
```

I know I can get a distinct list and do an identity insert into a table, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to create the unique id for each row:

```
create view [My Dimension] as
select 
  row_number() over(order by drug_class) drugid,
  drug_class,
  drug_name
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/effa6/1)

Comment: Completely spaced, didn't even think about row_number() and I use window functions all the time! >.<

Comment: @wootscootinboogie no problem, we have all done that before. :)